# Divergence of integrals

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If I have two functions $f$ and $g$ and aim at computing:
$$I:=\int (f-g) = \int f - \int g$$
in some region and I find out:
$$\int f = \int g = +\infty.$$

Can I conclude that $I=\infty$? Or is there a possibility for "cancellation" of infinities? I got a bit confused at this point.

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Not necessarily.  Trivially you can take $f = g$.  Like $f(x) = g(x) = 1/x$ where the integral is over $[0,+\infty)$.  I'll post an actual answer if I can come up with a nontrivial example later but someone else will likely get there first.

Comment: Even simpler, take $f = g = 1$, the constant functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if $f(t)=\frac1t$ and $g(t)=\frac{(1-t)^n}{t}$ then
$$
\int_0^1 (f(t)-g(t)) dt = H_n = 1+\frac12+\frac13 + \dots + \frac1n
$$
but the integrals taken separately diverge

Comment: That's a really cool integral.